# How do I create parent and children models at the same time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a one to many relationship between a Parent and child model. How do I save the parent and nested children in one go?

Essentially. complete the following

```
# assumed @parent and @children is set
# @parent is attributes for parent
# @children is an array of @child attributes
def create
  p = Parent.new @parent
  p.what_do_i_do @children # what do I do here?
  p.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model
2. Use `children_attributes` in the controller

Code:

```
# model
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

# controller
def create
  p = Parent.new @parent
  p.children_attributes = @children
  p.save
end
```